# How to set OpenGL version?

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, glfw

I am beginner in OpenGL, I am using latest opengl and GLFW libraries for windows context handling.

I have two graphics cards in my laptop:

1. Intel HD Graphics 3000
2. Nvidia GT 540 m

But when I run

```
const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string

printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);
```

output:

Renderer: Intel HD Graphics 3000
OpenGL version supported 3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.3223

My question is, how can I set default graphic card to NVIDIA and opengl version to 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The videocard combo you have works in switchable mode, meaning that you can offload work to the NVIDIA when performance are needed and fall back to the (less demanding) Intel to save battery.

That said, you have either to force enable NVIDIA card from BIOS (if possible) or use [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html)/[Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) to launch your application with access to the NVIDIA card.